# SetInitializer for database erring

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to convert the sample ASP.Net post; ASP.NET Identity: Using MySQL Storage with an EntityFramework MySQL Provider (C#)
[Project found here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider)

The following code is from the sample

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  static ApplicationDbContext()
  {
      Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
  }

  public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
  {
  }
}
```

This converts to vb.net as shown below

```
Public Class ApplicationDbContext
Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)
Shared Sub New()
            'the code is erring here on the next line
    Database.SetInitializer(New MySqlInitializer())
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
End Sub
```

End Class

The Initializer class is as follows

```
Public Class MySqlInitializer
    Implements IDatabaseInitializer(Of ApplicationDbContext)

    Public Sub InitializeDatabase(context As ApplicationDbContext) Implements IDatabaseInitializer(Of ApplicationDbContext).InitializeDatabase
        If Not context.Database.Exists() Then               
            context.Database.Create()
        Else

            Dim migrationHistoryTableExists = DirectCast(context, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of Integer)(String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'","connstring"))

            If migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() = 0 Then
                context.Database.Delete()
                context.Database.Create()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code is erring in the Database.SetInitializer(New MySqlInitializer()) code line with the error

Error 31262 Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class. C:\WebAppTemplate\AspNetIdentityTemplate_MySql\AspNetIdentityTemplate_MySql\Models\IdentityModels.vb 14 9 AspNetIdentityTemplate_MySql

A blue squiggly under Database in the line DataBase.SetInitializer...

All my attempts to rectify result in same or other errors. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post contains an error in one of the code samples.

The line that is highlighted corresponds to an argument for that string.Format method, however the argument is supposed to be a database schema name, not a connection string.

If you have a database named users then you should specify `"users"` here.

[image]
[image]